# File with simple text mixed with html - split on parts

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I need to parse some text from some files and split ti by parts, depends on is it simple text part of text or html.

Let's say, this is example text

```
This section should include any considerations for:

<ul>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>A</li>
</ul>

h1. Support Contracts

<p>simple par</p>
```

And it should be splitted like that (used JSON notation, because of it was fast to write, doesnt matter what type of the container is there)

```
 [{
     part: 1,
     text: "This section should include any considerations for:" 
    }, 
    {
     part: 2,
     text:"<ul> <li>C</li><li>B</li> <li>A</li></ul>"
    },
    {
     part: 3,
     text:"h1. Support Contracts"
    },
    {
     part: 4,
     text:"<p>simple par</p>"
    }]
```

Html there is really simple and all tags are guaranteed closed (it generated by program)

What the way is most faster (without using any third-party libs)? Can I use regex here for this task?

Comment: *it generated by program*: it isn't a proof.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte well, let just imagine that then. At least conditions are so

Comment: Why not load as HTML document? Then pull out the relevant sections? Then your code will be much more robust, and will be a lot more readable. What you're doing is parsing HTML, so best to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Why `<!-- Part 3. -->` is indented? Is there other html comments?

Comment: @Baldrick yeah, I was thinking about that, but `XDocument` fails (due it's not an xhtml file), third-party libraries are restricted

Comment: @Baldrick I can use `WebBroswer` afaik but is it okay to use it like that?

Comment: It is unclear to me what differentiates between `Part 1` and `Part 3`.  Both are just plain text. Can you maybe clarify the example. What would the incoming text look like and what are the parts you are expecting to end up with?  In regards to the HTML, is it just a subset of HTML (your example has only list tags)?  When you say "split" into parts, do you want the HTML tags removed or do they still need to be there?

Comment: @pstrjds okay, I'll update the question

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack seems to be a popular option for doing this with ordinary html: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @pstrjds html tags should still be there

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - Are `<` and `>` considered valid characters in the plain text? For example: "This is some plain text where we say that 3 > 2"

Comment: @pstrjds yes, valid

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - What is the expected splitting if the text was something like this "My friend has a new dog <puppy>\n<p>simple paragraph</p>\n"His dog</puppy> is pretty big." - yes, this is contrived, but I am wondering if you have to validate the html tags or is it sufficient to find <some words></some words> to split.

Comment: @pstrjds oh, sorry, I get it! anything which looks like a tag would be valid

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - Another example - would this split as one part or three parts or be considered invalid? "This text is <b>BOLD</b> but the rest of it is not"

Comment: @pstrjds 3 parts, looks like all tags are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirements properly, I am not sure I would tackle this with a regular expression.  It seems like it would be simple enough to just walk the text looking for the tags and building a list of pieces as you go.

```
var pieces = new List<string>();
int current = 0;
while (current < text.Length)
{
    var first = text.IndexOf('<', current);
    if (first != -1)
    {
        var second = text.IndexOf('>', first);
        if (second != -1)
        {
            var tag = text.Substring(first+1, (second-first-1));
            var closeTag = $"</{tag}>";
            var close = text.IndexOf(closeTag, second+1);
            if (close != -1)
            {
                close += closeTag.Length;
                if (current < first)
                {
                    pieces.Add(text.Substring(current, (first-current)).Trim());
                }
                current = close + 1;
                pieces.Add(text.Substring(first, (close-first)).Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                current = second + 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            current = first+1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pieces.Add(text.Substring(current).Trim());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, well, I like that, simple and straightforward)

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - Using a couple sample texts put together of 52,000 characters and running the parsing in a loop of 1000 iterations it took just over a second to parse on my system.  You could probably clean the code up a little, not sure if you need/want the `Trim` calls.  Also, validate it. I did test it a little, but there may be off-by-one errors.

Comment: Sorry for not answering, was idle